# LoopBack 3.0: where filter not returning results from REST API

Tags: rest, loopbackjs

I have a LoopBack API with a single simple model like this:

```
{
  "name": "Establishment",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "Distance": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "EstablishmentId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "EstablishmentType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "MinCost": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "Name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Stars": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "UserRating": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "UserRatingTitle": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "UserRatingCount": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "ImageUrl": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ThumbnailUrl": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

A simple call to `http://localhost:3000/api/Establishments` returns all of the results, as expected; but a call to `http://localhost:3000/api/Establishments?filter[where][distance][gt]=30` yields no results at all: an empty array.

There are lots of `Establishment`s with a `Distance` greater than 30; and indeed using the `where` filter on other properties also results in an empty array. What could I be missing?

Comment: maybe because its case sensitive try renaming your fields on your model to lowercase first letter or just use "Distance" in your filter

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, it is case-sensitive and I varified it on my app to be certain about it.

it should be :

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Establishments?filter[where][Distance][gt]=30
```

or you can try with this format :

```
http://localhost:3000/api/Establishments?filter={"where":{"Distance":{"gt":30}}}
```

Comment: I was under the impression URLs are not case-sensitive. In any case, the first suggestion does not work, and the second still returns establishments where the distance is less than 30.

Comment: @serlingpa please add this scope to your establishment.json `"scope": {
    "where": {
      "Distance": {"gt":30}
    }
  }` and call this `http://localhost:3000/api/Establishments` is it he same result ?